# How do I keep meteor clients in sync? (animation)

Tags: meteor

I'm looking for ideas on how to keep clients in sync when animating. I'm trying to build a browser based teleprompter using meteor. I have the basic functionality down, I can set font-size & scroll speed, but I haven't figured out a reliable way to keep all the clients in sync once the scrolling starts.

So far I have tried two ways, both work, but neither is perfect.

My first idea was to run an interval on the server which updates a Collection with the position. This works decently on the LAN, but once I move to the internet the lag time between updates and the updates being observed on the client caused the scrolling to stutter.  Here's what that code looked like:

Server:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.methods({
        start_scroll: function(){
            interval = Meteor.setInterval(function() {
                var _speed = Prompter.findOne({_var:"prompter_speed"})._val;
                Prompter.update({_var:"prompter_y"}, {$inc:{_val:(-1*_speed/4)}});
            }, 30);
        }, ...
}
```

Client:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Prompter.find({_var: "prompter_y"}).observe({
        changed: function(pos){
            $("#inner_scroll").css({top: pos._val});
        }
    });
}
```

The main issue with the above version is that any latency in observing the update causes the animation to stutter. So, I decided to do the animating on the client side. Here's what I came up with for that:

Server:

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
    Meteor.methods({
        start_move: function(){
            Prompter.update({_var:"prompter_move"},{$set:{_val:1}});
        }, ...
}
```

Client:

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Prompter.find({_var: "prompter_move"}).observe({
        changed: function(obj){
            if(obj._val == 1){
                interval = Meteor.setInterval(function(){
                    var cp = parseFloat($("#inner_scroll").css("top"));
                    var sp = parseInt(Session.get("_speed"));
                    var mv = cp + (-1 * sp)/4;
                    $("#inner_scroll").css("top", mv);
                }, 30);
            }
            else{
                Meteor.clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The animation is very smooth on the client with this version, but (due to the latency in observing the "start" update) the clients may not start at the same time and thus are not in sync. The other issue I noticed with this is that some slower clients (in terms of CPU performance) scroll slower with this version.

I'm scratching my head on this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using a timestamp comparison to keep everything in sync. When the server receives an update request it creates a timestamp. The timestamp is passed along with the updated data so the client can compare the timestamp to "now" and adjust accordingly.

Still open to other suggestions, but this is working pretty well for me.